# finding parent of my executable program

Tags: linux

I have a code and I want to see who the parent of this program is.  What do I have to write as a command for that? I used "-ps" but I didn't see my program there. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `getppid` function implements this[1]:

On the command line, do this:

```
ps -e --heading -O ppid

ps --heading -O ppid $(pgrep -f zsh)
```

PID and PPID are Process ID and Parent Process ID. On the command line, use `ps` or `procfs` to find out more information:

```
 cat /proc/self/cmdline
 ls -ltrad /proc/self/exe
```

etc.

---

[1]

- http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/functions/getppid.html

  #### NAME

  `getppid` - get the parent process ID

  #### SYNOPSIS

  ```
  #include <unistd.h>

  pid_t getppid(void);
  ```

  #### DESCRIPTION

  The getppid() function shall return the parent process ID of the calling process.

  #### RETURN VALUE

  The getppid() function shall always be successful and no return value is reserved to indicate an error.

  #### ERRORS

  ```
  No errors are defined.
  ```

Comment: Yes. It is like `getpid` but return the PID of the parent process!

Comment: Hmm,ok I can see the parent but what are these numbers represent?

Comment: Ok I also did something like that:

lambda05:~> ps -ef |grep 29512
atanakol 29512 29511  0 15:07 pts/1    00:00:00 -csh

Could you give information about this -csh ?

Comment: On the command line, do this: `ps -e --heading -O ppid` (or `ps  --heading -O ppid $(pgrep -f zsh)`

Comment: Yes I found the parent:29512 29511 S pts/1    00:00:00 -csh